# how to disable evince-thumbnailer

Tags: evince

I would like to disable evince-thumbnailer because capacity of log file keeps increasing.

Let me know how to disable evince-thumbnailer.

Comment: ...killing the patient because the symptoms ;-) --- maybe you can try to see why "the capacity" of your "log file" (not clear to what are you referring to here) is increasing...

Comment: @Rmano this is the case where the patient should indeed be put down.

Answer (score 9):

To disable it system-wide, comment the `Exec=` line in `/usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=/# &/' /usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer
```

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=/# &/' /usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % cat /usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=evince-thumbnailer
# Exec=evince-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/x-xzpdf;application/x-ext-pdf;application/postscript;application/x-bzpostscript;application/x-gzpostscript;image/x-eps;image/x-bzeps;image/x-gzeps;application/x-ext-ps;application/x-ext-eps;application/x-dvi;application/x-bzdvi;application/x-gzdvi;application/x-ext-dvi;image/vnd.djvu;application/x-ext-djv;application/x-ext-djvu;image/tiff;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;application/x-cb7;application/x-cbt;application/x-ext-cbr;application/x-ext-cbz;application/x-ext-cb7;application/x-ext-cbt;application/oxps;application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument
```

To re-enable it, uncomment it again:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^# \(Exec=\)/\1/' /usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer
```

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % sudo sed -i 's/^# \(Exec=\)/\1/' /usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % cat /usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=evince-thumbnailer
Exec=evince-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/x-xzpdf;application/x-ext-pdf;application/postscript;application/x-bzpostscript;application/x-gzpostscript;image/x-eps;image/x-bzeps;image/x-gzeps;application/x-ext-ps;application/x-ext-eps;application/x-dvi;application/x-bzdvi;application/x-gzdvi;application/x-ext-dvi;image/vnd.djvu;application/x-ext-djv;application/x-ext-djvu;image/tiff;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;application/x-cb7;application/x-cbt;application/x-ext-cbr;application/x-ext-cbz;application/x-ext-cb7;application/x-ext-cbt;application/oxps;application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument
```

Comment: Great, +1 one question >:) what's about TryExec?

Comment: @A.B. It simply checks if what follows it is an executable present in `$PATH`, before running what follows `Exec=`. Early-rising as well huh? :D

Answer (score 8):

Just `sudo apt-get remove evince` and install okular. This help my poor thinkpad don't freeze any more.

Comment: Somehow I had absolutely random runs (not related to any user action) of evince-thumbnailer causing CPU core to go 100% which is from the `evince` package - ***Evince is just a document viewer*** - it should generally be safe to remove it and install some different document viewer :)

Comment: @jiamo OH MY GOD THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

kos' answer is the way to go. However, the implementation can be easier. Just:

```
cd /usr/share/thumbnailers
sudo nano evince.thumbnailer 
# enter superuser password
# then uncomment the Exec line by entering a # sign as the first character in the line
# exit nano with Ctrl-X, press y, press Enter, DONE!
```